# How to deploy a a java application on a WildFly (Or any App Server) through jenkins groovy script?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I wanted to deploy a java application on a WildFly server or any application server through jenkins script. Can any one help me in providing the syntax or command?

```
pipeline {
 agent any

   stages {
       stage('Code Checkout') {
         steps {
           git(url: 'http://github.com/ ', branch: 'master ', poll: true, credentialsId: '', changelog: true)
         }

       }


       stage('Build') {
         steps {
           withMaven(jdk: 'jdk8', maven: 'mvn3') {
               sh 'mvn clean package'
           }
         }
       }
   }
```

Here I want the syntax for deploying application on wildfly or any server.

Comment: What problems are you running into?

Comment: @mkobit I am not knowing how to run the application on specific server, I want the code that to be written in groovy stage

Comment: This questions is in the territory of "code writing request" because you have not posted what you have tried. It looks like there are plenty of WildFly tutorials and documentation on the internet, so what is not working for you?